# Zbar R cannot be resovled

Tags: android, eclipse, zbar

I have just imported the zbar example project into eclipse. I have started the AVD, but when I go to run the zbar example I get a pop-up saying there are errors in the code.

[image]

When I went looking for errors the only ones I could find are the ones shown below

[image]

I removed the project from eclipse and re-downloaded the zip file and imported it all again but still have the same results. Has anyone else run into this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 `R` classes now in your app:

- your own's app `R` class (from your app's namespace).
- zbar's `R` class

You should either sort out the `import` instruction to make sure you import the right `R` class or use a full namespace in front of `R`.

Comment: The help has been much appreciated :)

Comment: You're welcome. So it was actually a problem with target build platform?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the wrong target build platform being selected when I was importing it.

Solution:

1. Right click on project->properties.
2. Select Android on left panel.
3. Tick Android 4.4.2